# How do the versions of Frederik Pohl's Gateway differ?

Tags: edition-comparison, heechee-saga

When I checked *Gateway* by Frederik Pohl out of the library (it having been recommended to me by a librarian, based on the fact that my favorite book up to that time was *Watership Down*), I discovered something rather unusual about the text.  The regular printed text ended with Robinette Broadhead finishing his last appointment with his computer psychoanalyst Sigfrid.  However, another short chapter (one narrow column of small print) was taped into the back of the book.
The passage seemed as if it had been cut from a magazine or something printed on similar paper, and it told briefly of Robinette meeting up with S. Ya. Lavarovna and finally seeing something of a worthwhile future before him.

I know that before it was published as free-standing novel, *Gateway* was serialized.  Was the last chapter something that was published in the last part of the magazine version, which was subsequently cut from the novel (and restored by a diligent librarian)?  Or, if not, what are the statuses of the different version of the text?

Comment: I'm trying figure out why your librarian recommended "Gateway" based on a liking of "Watership Down." I am at a loss for a connection.

Comment: @JRE I added that note specifically because of the oddity of the whole situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As stated by [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_(novel))

> Gateway was serialized in *Galaxy* prior to its hardcover publication. A short concluding chapter, cut before publication, was later published in the August 1977 issue of *Galaxy*.

There have been numerous editions and versions (see this [list](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1884)) but I cannot comment on whether this additional "chapter" is included an any specific version.

However, my ebook version (which is the Del Rey 2004 version) *does* include the Pohl article explaining it's omission and the final chaper itself which is brief enough to copy here.

> **Chapter XXXII**
>
> Under the bubble the late afternoon sun was warm and gentle. It was late, but I went right to the club: shower, plunge, ten minutes in the sauna; and when I came out I was ready for my date with S. Ya. I was more than ready. I was looking forward to it. Not only for S. Ya. herself, pretty, intelligent, kind as she was. I wanted very much to make love to her, but I also wanted to talk to her.
>
> All that stuff Sigfrid was giving me—was it his crazy electronic fantasy? Or was it real? S. Ya. would know, or at least know enough to talk sensibly about the possibility of laying machine emotions onto machine intelligence.
>
> Oh, I had not forgotten Klara! She was still in my heart, as much as ever—more than ever, because underneath the pain and the guilt were the tenderness and the love, that I would have for always, wherever rcal-Klara was.
>
> I have all my parts back again; I am whole and as well as any living thing is ever going to be. . .which, I decide, is good enough for me. I have even got something I want to do! I owe Sigfrid a favor. He healed me. . . .
>
> Maybe, with a little help from S. Ya. and the Grace of God and Good Fortune, I can make at least a start toward healing him.
>
> [THE END]
>
> <sup>*Gateway* - Frederick Pohl</sup>